# List-building with foreach-loop and text based instancing

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I need to program a management for a robot factory. Therefore I have a configuration file as a .txt. Every line in this text file is a configuration for a working station.

```
Eingangslager EL01 A1 INITIALISIEREN
Ausgangslager AL01 G1 EINLAGERN
Fertigungsinsel FI01 A3 TRENNEN
Fertigungsinsel FI02 C3 FRAESEN 
Fertigungsinsel FI03 E3 BESCHICHTEN
Fertigungsinsel FI04 G3 LOETEN
```

My first question: Will VisualStudio recognize this .txt as a whole string or will it divide the pieces into separate strings? Because I want to iterate through this text file and make for every line a list. and it the second loop I want to put the columns into each list. Because I don't know how to make a new name for every list in the first loop. Thank you!

I got this junk of code. Could I use it for making a list?

```
foreach (List<string> listenZeile in KonfigurationenLader.LeseKonfiguration(@"Resources/Produktrezept.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string verarbeitungsschritt in listenZeile)
            {
                // Beispiel der Konvertierung von 'string' zu einem Enumerations-Typ.
                verarbeitungsschrittliste.Add((Verarbeitungsschritt)Enum.Parse(typeof(Verarbeitungsschritt), verarbeitungsschritt));
```

Comment: Visual Studio can do one of several things: It can ignore your file, it can copy your file to the output directory, or it can embed your file as a resource. In the latter two options, it is up to you to write the code to read and process that file, so no. "Visual Studio" won't do anything to the *contents* of that file at all. It'll either copy or embed or ignore **the file** as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will adhere to what the file extension is.  Your modification, will change based on what you do to the resource, for instance do you want it to be an embedded resource?

Otherwise, when you utilize the C# language, you can read the file line by line.

```
var collection = new List<string>();
using(var stream = new StreamReader(path)
     while(!stream.EndOfStream())
          collection.Add(stream.ReadLine());
```

The example I posted, would simply add each line to the collection.  But you could modify or append approach within the `while loop`.  Or you could do the above, then break it apart, and use Linq to rebuild.  Without more detail, we have an abundance of approaches.

Comment: I would like to take the easiest way to do it. Because I want to have 6 lists with 4 items and it can be extended :) . I am new to C# so I do not know what a embedded resource or collection is.